# leetcode perfect square, removing inner loop went wrong

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am working on [perfect square](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/)

One of the recursive [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/perfect-squares/solutions/870288/javascript-recursive-and-dp/) is below

```
function rc (n, cache = {}) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;
    if (cache[n] !== undefined) return cache[n]
    let min = Infinity;
    for (let i = 1; i * i <= n; i++) {
        min = Math.min(1 + rc(n - i * i, cache), min);
    }
    return cache[n] = min;
}
```

I tried to remove the for loop, but not sure what went wrong. Is it a way to remove inner loop?

```
var numSquares = function(n) {
    const hash = {};
    let min = Infinity;

    const dfs = (num, ind) => {
        // * b: base (bad)
        if(num < 0) return Infinity;

        // * b: base (bound)
        const half_num = Math.floor(Math.sqrt(num));
        if(ind > half_num) return Infinity;

        // * b: base (good)
        if(num === 0) return 0;

        // * b: state: num and ind
        // * b: decision
        const n_take = dfs(num, ind+1);
        const take = 1 + dfs(num - ind*ind, ind+1);

        min = Math.min(n_take, take);
          
        return min;
    }

    // * b: state: num
    const res = dfs(n, 1);
    return res;
};
```

Comment: It's not really a 0/1 knapsack problem. It's an unbounded knapsack problem ([as defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Definition)). That makes a difference when, for example, `n` is 12, since the squares needed are 4+4+4. I see nothing  in the code that allows the same number to be used more than once.

Comment: @user3386109, yes correct, my bad, it is unbounded. Do you know how to remove the inner loop?

Comment: @user3386109, I tried that (code above), but not sure what went wrong, hence this post

Comment: _"not sure what went wrong"_ Is not a good description of the problem you are facing.  How do you know something is wrong?  At least describe this from the perspective of how you discovered the problem. (even if it's just: e.g. "This didn't pass some of the automated tests that leetcode runs when I submitted the code.")  It would be even better if you did some of your own testing and revealed which test cases fail and why (i.e., disclose the details of your attempt to debug it.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues:

- With the recursive call `1 + dfs(num - ind*ind, ind+1)` you don't allow the same square (`ind*ind`) to be used a second time. To correct this, you should pass the same value for the `ind` argument:

  ```
  const take = 1 + dfs(num - ind*ind, ind);
  ```
- The check `if(num === 0) return 0;` happens too late. There is a risk that the previous exit point kicks in, when `if(ind > half_num)` is true. However, that is not a reason to reject this valid solution. So the `num === 0` case should be checked earlier on.
- You don't use the cache. The variable `hash` is never used. You should use it as otherwise you will hit a time limit.

Some other, less essential remarks:

- Try to avoid `Math.sqrt`. It is more efficient to square `ind` and compare that with `num`.
- It is counter-intuitive to define `min` outside the `dfs` function. Just define it on the spot, so its scope is not excessive.

Here is your code updated with those remarks. See comments:

```
var numSquares = function(n) {
    const cache = {};
    
    const dfs = (num, ind) => {
        if (num < 0) return Infinity;
        // Do this first
        if (num === 0) return 0; 
        // Use the cache
        if (cache[num] !== undefined) return cache[num];

        // Avoid sqrt
        if (ind * ind > num) return Infinity;

        const n_take = dfs(num, ind+1);
        // Don't increase ind so the same square can be used again
        const take = 1 + dfs(num - ind*ind, ind);

        // Define the min variable with appropriate scope:
        const min = Math.min(n_take, take);
        // Add this result to the cache
        cache[num] = min;
        return min;
    }

    return dfs(n, 1);
};
```